# Calculate motion time CMMotionActivity?

Tags: ios, core-motion

I'm trying to calculate the time of motion (either walking or running).
Every CMMotionActivity object has a startDate property that indicates the time at which the activity started. But there is no indication the end time.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every CMMotionActivity object is succeeded by *another* CMMotionActivity object. Each has a `startDate` property that indicates the time at which the activity started. Thus, the end time of each CMMotionActivity object is given by the `startDate` of its successor.